# Android Hilt DI

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel
@Inject constructor(private val authApi: AuthApi) : ViewModel() {

    private val _hidePassword = MutableLiveData(false)
    val hidePassword: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _hidePassword


    private val _autoLogin = MutableLiveData(false)
    val autoLogin: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _autoLogin

    private val _loginError = MutableLiveData(false)

    val loginError: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _loginError


    fun login(userId: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            kotlin.runCatching {
                authApi.login(
                    LoginReqeustDto(
                        userId = userId,
                        password = password
                    )
                )
            }.onSuccess {
//                val prefs = NewJeansBunniesApplication.prefs
//                prefs.accessToken = it.accessToken
//                prefs.autoLogin = autoLogin.value?:false
//                if(autoLogin.value == true)
//                    prefs.refreshToken = it.refreshToken
//                _loginError.value = false
            }.onFailure { e ->
                _loginError.value = true
                Log.d("LoginViewModel", e.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun loginError(status: Boolean) {
        _loginError.value = status
    }

    fun autoLogin(status: Boolean) {
        _autoLogin.value = status
    }

    fun hidePassword(status: Boolean) {
        _hidePassword.value = status
    }

}
```

If you enter the LoginViewModel parameter like that, a Cannot create an instance of class newjeans.bunnies.auth.viewmodel.LoginViewModel error appears, but if you remove the private val authApi: AuthApi, it works normally.

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(): AuthApi =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
            .create(AuthApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        loggerInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        okHttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggerInterceptor)

        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
}
```

Inject dependency like this

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AuthActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = NavigationRoute.loginRoute
            ) {
                composable(NavigationRoute.loginRoute) {
                    LoginScreen(
                        loginViewModel = loginViewModel,
                        onNavigateToSignup = { navController.navigate(NavigationRoute.signupRoute) }
                    )
                }
                composable(NavigationRoute.signupRoute) {
                    SignupScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

loginviewModel is used here

I tried changing the version and using hiltViewModel(), but all errors occurred.

Comment: Why are you creating a different Retrofit instance when providing **AuthApi**?

Comment: I think you must use repository module rather directly using API into viewmodel.

Comment: Even if I create a repository, an error appears.